# What is the DotNet Core alternative to AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit event?

Tags: .net, .net-core

I want to do some cleanup in a library when the process is being closed, what is the DotNet Core alternative for that? In .Net Framework 4 I used AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit.

Comment: Can't you add `finally` to your `Main`?

Comment: Another option might be [`AssemblyLoadContext.Unloading`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/api/system.runtime.loader.assemblyloadcontext#System_Runtime_Loader_AssemblyLoadContext_Unloading).

Comment: It is a library, so I don't have an access to the main method

Comment: @svick can you turn the AssemblyLoadContext comment into an answer ? it seems to work, thank!

Comment: @svick it works but actually not doing exactly what I'm doing. Because I have a thread open the unloading never being called.

Comment: Seems to have a time limit attached to it. My code isn't finishing when I use AssemblyLoadContext.Unloading :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your code is in a library you can make the caller of the library provide a notification. That way the host can decide to notify you.

Normally, a library is not supposed to mess with process global state. It should not assume much about the environment it's being hosted it.

Maybe the caller can pass a `Task` that becomes completed when process shutdown starts. Or, the caller can call a static method on your library (`NotifyProcessShutdown` or `PerformProcessShutdownCleanup`).

Comment: The library (NetMQ) start a dedicate thread when you first use it, you can manually kill the thread as well, however I want to make sure I'm killing the thread when the library exit.

Comment: As there is no solution, I added a Cleanup method that should be called by the user.

Answer (score 0):

There is no alternative to [`AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appdomain.processexit?view=netcore-3.1) in .NET-Core, the same event is used.

However, if you want to do cleanup in a library, I recommend either of the following two methods:

- Adding a `void Shutdown()` (or something similar) to an interface of your library which the main application would call.
- Using `IDisposable` in your library, so the library can clean itself up when disposed.

Then, the main application would use `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit` and trigger one of the mechanisms above.

Answer (score 0):

It's back since .net core 2.0 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appdomain.processexit?view=net-5.0